Can "How many" be followed by "be + a determiner"?

Q: Are there many wild animals in your country?
A: I'm not sure how many are many.

I searched for "How many are many" and I saw a closed question that asked the question "How many is many" link.
But it's not the definition of "many" that I want to ask.
I want to know if the phrase ""How many is many" (the closed question I attached the link above) and/or "How many are many" are grammatical and idiomatic. And the same question applied to "How many are + a determiner" and "How much is + a determiner".

This is a pointless question. Native Anglophones don't waste their time thinking about the "syntactically correct plurality" of How X is/are X? when it just means What exactly do you mean by X? As it happens, Brits are much more likely to use singular is, whereas Americans just use both, but I don't suppose many people would notice or care which you used with the specific "quantity" many.

...note that there are far more instance of the "quantity" too many being queried in this way, so that's what I searched for in the above chart. But too makes no difference to the plurality question itself.

Actually what I wanted to ask is whether “How many is many” is idiomatic to say @FumbleFingers (as when I was speaking to my friend, I used this phrase but then wondered if it was natural enough.

Yes, the format How [adjective] is [adjective] is perfectly idiomatic for a wide range of adjectives (and adjectival phrases such as too many, big enough, very often...) where qualifiers (too, enough, very...) are only specified with the second instance of the base adjective (many, big, often,...). If the adjective is something that could correspond to a number (such as many, few,...) some people (especially Americans) will treat it as a plural for such Please quantify what you mean by X utterances. But I think singular is always at least "acceptable".
